# Showing roots of cubic polynomial are purely imaginary without explicitly calculating the roots?

Tags: polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots

**Background**
We can show that the roots of a cubic polynomial, $P=\lambda^3+a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c$, have non-zero complex components by determining when the discriminant of $P$ is negative.

**Question**
Is there a way to determine when $P$'s roots have real parts equal to zero without explicitly calculating the roots?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with eigenvalues/vectors. Are $a, b, c$ complex?

Comment: Eigenvalues? Of which matrix? Did you mean "roots"?

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, I meant roots; I updated the question. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Q(\lambda) = iP(i\lambda) = \lambda^3 - ai \lambda^2 - b\lambda + ci$. Note that the roots of $P$ are precisely the roots of $Q$, but multiplied by $i$. So, the roots of $P$ will be purely imaginary if and only only if the roots of $Q$ are purely real.

From this, we can see that $b$ must be purely real, and $a$ and $c$ must be purely imaginary. We can apply the discriminant to the polynomial $Q$ to test whether or not it has purely real roots. Assuming $a$ and $c$ are imaginary, and $b$ is real, then $Q$ has real roots (and $P$ has imaginary roots) if and only if

\begin{align*}
0 &\le (-ai)^{2}(-b)^{2}-4(-b)^{3}-4(-ai)^{3}(ci)-27(ci)^{2}+18(-ai)(-b)ci \\
&= -a^2b^2 + 4b^3 + 4a^3c + 27c - 18abc.
\end{align*}

To summarise: $P(\lambda) = \lambda^3 + a\lambda^2 + b\lambda + c$, where $a, b, c \in \Bbb{C}$, has purely imaginary roots if and only if:

- $a$ and $c$ are purely imaginary,
- $b$ is real, and
- $0 \le -a^2b^2 + 4b^3 + 4a^3c + 27c - 18abc$

If $a, b, c \in \Bbb{R}$, this simplifies down to $a = c = 0$, and $b \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for